# how to take linux shell backup script system?

Tags: linux, shell

I am facing problem in taking shell script backup of my system (Linux). Please help me to know how to take shell script backup of my system.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have tried anything? Any Google(ing)? A very broad question, and you also did not even define the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer rsync for backing up my Centos boxes. It is very good at both file transfer and file synchronization and offers tons of options for compression and such. This is a modified one line example from my BASH backup script that backs up all of my media onto a temporarily mounted external hard drive:

```
rsync -avP --stats /media/* /mnt/ntfs/Media 1>/log/stats.info 2>>log/bkup.err
```

You can substitute `/media/*` with the directories you want to backup; the most simple would simply be `/*`, which will backup everything.

You can also use the `--exclude` directive to exclude directories.

The other simple method is a simple tar archive to get all the important system files, something like:

```
tar cvfj /root/sysBkup.bz2 --exclude=/root/sysBkup.bz2 /etc /var /root /sys
```

Then moving that backup to a remote share with the next line of bash script. But I would recommend getting familiar with rsync; very handy backup utility.